# ObjC Button Released Touch Up Outside

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a button, when held down motion occurs, when released it should stop.  I know I could write two methods, one to start and one to stop motion, I was wondering if in the one method I could detect both based on Touch Up Outside vs. Touch Up Inside.

If Touch Up Outside do this if Inside do this.

```
-(IBAction) startMotion: (id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Forward or back button is being pressed.");
    UIButton * buttonName = (UIButton *) sender;
        NSLog(@"Button Name:  %@",  buttonName.currentTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could write *one* method and link the IBAction "touchUpInside" and "touchUpOutside" to the *same* IBAction member function - via Interface Builder.

The only downside would be that you would *not* be able to tell if it was a touchUp inside or outside when it was called. (It doesn't sound like this matters to you.)

If the later was an issue, you could alternately implement independent touchUpInside and touchUpOutside methods which in turn call the *same* method - a third custom one - into which you could pass an "inside" or "outside" flag from the proper IBAction handler.

Answer (score 1):

Touch up Outside won't give you the functionality you're looking for, I don't think.  The person would have to move their finger outside the boundaries of the button and then lift remove the finger
Why not use touchdown to initiate the motion and touch up inside to stop it?